# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex not working

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I'm trying to use the Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex in an application but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

I've set up a very basic instance:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                        '/developer/test/(d+)',
    array('controller' => 'developer', 'action' => 'module','module'=>'topic')      
    );
    $router->addRoute('apiModule2', $route);
```

and the corresponding action:

```
public function moduleAction()
{
    $this->view->module = 'topic';
}
```

However, every time I visit localhost/developer/test/1, I get a No Route Matched exception.

I believe this is all set up properly because if I use the same exact code changing only Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex to Zend_Controller_Router_route and the match url to match against to 'developer/test/1' it all works perfectly.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's the reason, but there is no regex in your route... try /developer/(test)/(test)

Comment: Thanks Frederik, but unfortunately adding a more regex to the route didn't help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct route to match

> http://localhost/developer/test/1

is

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                    'developer/test/(\d+)',
array('controller' => 'developer', 'action' => 'module','module'=>'topic')      
);
```

You should not have leading slash(before the developer) and d+ should be \d+.

Comment: Thanks emaillenin, I tried using a more explicit regex (as detailed in the modified question) and still no luck. Not sure why it won't match against anything